# Can I use an atk4 Model for this?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, atk4

I've been braking my brain tryig to figure out how to model this, instead of going on low level php.
So I have these models/tables:

Student (id,name).
Program (id, name,  startdate, enddate, firstpaymentDueDate, qtyOfPeriods, price).

I have to register the application of a student into a program that consist on several months.
So I want to populete a table:
paymentSchedule (id, student_id,  dueDate, amount)
Since one program can have upto 10 periods, I would need to add auto 10 records in the paymentSchedule for each student application.
My question is if this can be modeled?

I would leter use the paymentSchedule to take records for payments and insert them into a transactions table.

Thanks for all your support, and thanks for developing such great toolkit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER: **YES**, you can model this in ATK4

You basically have all the tables perfectly set up.

To create a model, simply create a file Student.php and place it
in your /lib/Model/ folder.

```
 class Model_Student extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code = 'Student';

    function init() {
       parent::init();

       $this->addField('name')->caption('Student Name');
    }
 }
```

You can do the same for your other tables:

`Program (id, name, startdate, enddate, firstpaymentDueDate, qtyOfPeriods, price)`
and
`paymentSchedule (id, student_id, dueDate, amount)`

To know more about models, i suggest you read the intro:
http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/model/intro

---

Processing a table, like `paymentSchedule` is a different
story altogether. You need DSQL (Dynamic SQL) to do this.

Assuming your `Program` table is in a model class named
`Model_Program`. To retrieve an entry:

```
 $m = $this->add('Model_Program');
 $v = $m->dsql()
    ->field('qtyOfPeriods')
    ->field('price')
    ->where('id=',$programid) // specific program
    ->do_getOne();

 $m = $this->add('Model_PaymentSched');
 $r = $m->dsql()
    ->set('student_id',$studentid) // specific student
    ->set('amount',$v['price'])
    ->do_insert();
```

This will retrieve an entry for a particular program and
then insert it in the payment schedule:

Comment: Thanks, I was -don't know why- trying to do everything with MVCForm, and was not considering a regular form and simply do_insert on my dsql... You opened my eyes. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, you're welcome.. and i also understand your dillemma.. i've also started trying ATK4 just Dec last year.. and i learned that the stumbling block is how i am to put all these examples and combine it with the ideas in my head and make a functional end-to-end application.. the piece-by-piece example is good and interesting and works.. but putting them all together seems like a maze for first time users.. :)